# Why is the number of sample frequencies in `scipy.signal.stft()` tied to the hop size?

Tags: scipy, fft

This question relates to [SciPy's Short-time Fourier Transform](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.stft.html) function for signal processing.

For some reason I don't understand, the size of the output 'array of sample frequencies' is exactly equal to the hop size. From the documentation:

```
nperseg : int, optional

    Length of each segment. Defaults to 256.

noverlap : int, optional

    Number of points to overlap between segments. If None, noverlap = nperseg // 2. Defaults to None. When specified, the COLA constraint must be met (see Notes below).


f : ndarray

    Array of sample frequencies.

hop size H = nperseg - noverlap
```

I'm new to signal processing and Fourier transforms, but as far as I understand a STFT is just chopping an audio file into segments ('time frames') on which you perform a Fourier transform. So if I want to do a STFT on 100 time frames, I'd expect the output to be a matrix of size 100 x F, where F is an array of measured frequencies ('measured' probably isn't the right word here but you know what I mean).

This is kinda what SciPy's implementation does, but the size of `f` here is what bothers me. It's supposed to be an array describing the different frequencies, like `[0Hz  500Hz  1000Hz]`, and it does, but for some reasons its size exactly the same as the hop size. If the hop size is 700, the number of measured frequencies is 700.

The hop size is the number of samples (i.e. time) between each time frame, and is correctly calculated as `H = nperseg - noverlap`, but what does this have to do with the frequency array?

---

Edit: Related to [this question](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/55871/scipy-stft-how-is-shape-of-f-determined)

Comment: a typical input into a FFT call starts as a time series ... just a set of points on a curve ... like an audio signal or the stock ticker price of AMD stock .. something which varies up and down over time ... this curve lives in the time domain ... once you supply an array of these  data points into the fft call you get back that same data represented in the frequency domain ... in the array returned from the fft api call each element of the array typically contains a complex number which can be used to calculate the magnitude and phase shift ... each array element is the frequency

Comment: @ScottStensland Yes exactly. My question is why the number of frequencies in this array must be exactly equal to the number of samples between each time frame?

Comment: to quote my notes :          What do I do with the result of an FFT?
        https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/8952/what-do-i-do-with-the-result-of-an-fft

        If we collect 8192 samples for the FFT then we will have:

            8192 samples / 2 = 4096 FFT bins

        If our sampling rate is 10 kHz, then the Nyquist-Shannon sampling theorem says that our signal can contain frequency content up to 5 kHz.
        Then, our frequency bin resolution is:

            5 kHz / 4096 FFT bins = 1.22 Hz / bin

Comment: @ScottStensland Thanks, but this raises another question. The paramter `nfft` in stft() can be used to specify the length of the FFT. It can be equal to or greater than the number of segments in each time frame, but not less. So we can select more samples from each time frame for the FTT calculation, but the time frame size and the space between the frames remain the same. How?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An FFT is an square matrix transform from one orthogonal basis to another of the same dimension.  This is because N is the exact number of orthogonal (e.g. that don't interfere with one another) complex sinusoids that fit in a time domain vector of length N.

A longer time vector can contain more frequency information (e.g. it's hard to tell 2 frequencies apart using just 3 sample points, but much easier with 3000 samples, etc.)

You can zero-pad your short time vector of length N to use a longer FFT, but that is identical to interpolating a nice curve between N frequency points, which makes all the FFT results interdependent.

For many purposes (visualization, etc.) an STFT is overlapped, where the adjacent segments share some overlapped data instead of just being end-to-end.  This gives better time locality (e.g. the segments can be spaced closer but still be long enough so that each one can provide the frequency resolution required).

Comment: This is the correct answer, but it's too complicated for someone who hasn't studied Fourier transforms or signal processing (me).

Comment: @Mossmyr How do you intend to use the results of `stft` if you don't understand what it does?  o_O